# Grails store and fetch data on client side

Tags: caching, grails, cookies, local-storage

Background: We are using grails 2.1.1. We are not using any DB as of now. We make a web service call for each response on another server.

Now the problem is, there is web service call which returns some static data in XML form and this data is usable throughout the application. The size of the xml is around 40kb. This xml contains static data like, project_list, status_type_list etc. and we have to use this in various dropdowns and menu items in different gsp pages.

So, please suggest us the best way to handle this data. So that it doesn't effect our page load time and browsing experience. And also we can easily use the data on client side.

Comment: Where are you calling the web service from? client or the server? if it's the client, which I am assuming it is, then the cache plugin can't be used.

Comment: @uchamp: we are calling the webservices from our controllers and services, which in this case act as a client I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

responding to your comment on the question. I would prefer using annotation based caching over the plugin, if the requirement is as simple as you state that it is.

If the calls are being made from server-side and you want to cache the results of the parsed XML then you can do something like:

```
@Cacheable("staticDataCache")
def getStaticDataFromXML() {}
```

You can then use the above method to pull the maps, lists whatever data structure you've used to store the result and it will pull it from the cache.

and then another service method to flush the cache, which you can call frequently from a Job.

```
@CacheFlush("staticDataCache")
def flushStaticDataCache() {}
```

Comment: Thanx uchamp :) I never thought it was that simple. But can you suggest me (according to my requirements), should I go with cache or servletContext to store my data. As both is working for me now.

Comment: Accepting your answer though I am going to use the servletContext in my application.

Comment: nice! I didn't know it was that easy to store/retrieve stuff from the servletContext. Def. the way to go. Thanks for telling me about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) to cache the static xml data. And then add some policy as to when the cache should be updated... (i.e. using a job to check if the xml has changed every hour)

Comment: thanx for your response. And I guess this is the best alternative we can use. I have gone thru its documentation but couldn't find how to cache the list of map (parsed and converted from xml I am receiving from my webservice). Can u please help me out.